# Add control to NgFrom programmatically

Tags: angular

In ReactiveForm adding a form control is as easy as:
`this.myForm.addControl('newcontrol',[]);`
I want to do the same with `NgForm`.

```
  @ViewChild('myForm') myForm : NgForm;

  ngAfterViewInit(): void{
    this.myForm.addControl();    // But this method does not accept ('newcontrol',[])
  }
```

Is there any way I can achieve this? `addControl()` method here takes an NgModel instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The internal `FormGroup` of the `NgForm` lives under `control`, you can find that in the documentation under the **[properties](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgForm#properties)**. So you can add a form control by using `control`:

```ts
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  this.myForm.control.addControl('new', new FormControl('', []));
}
```

Off-topic: I suggest to use a Reactive Form though unless you have a good reason not to ;)

Comment: This is just for fitting in an existing code-base. Also, provided that template driven forms are pretty straight forward to implement, so having one non-standard input field shouldn't stop you from doing that. I also found a workaround with hidden input. But, thanks for the answer. Anguar even being such a beauty, is really lacking in community support.